# How to convert ajax retrieved object to string in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm looking to make an object containing latitudes and longitudes of various places such as `[["Second Event",19.0554748,72.8497017],["Demo Event",19.2097381,72.8737017]]`.

I'm successful of making this in `php` by using `json_encode()` function. How do I retrieve it in the callback function. I've tried the following:

```
$.post('maps1.php',{},function(data){
    alert(data);
    markers=JSON.stringify(data);
},"json");
alert(markers);
```

However this doesn't seems to work. What should I do?

Comment: Can you explain "this doesn't seems to work"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3):

You have the scope for the variable markers inside the post method, try doing it like this:

```
var markers = '';

$.post('maps1.php', {}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
    markers = JSON.stringify(data);
}, "json");

alert(markers)
```

Comment: @user1911914 Are you getting the alert for the data to appear?

Comment: @user1911914 To make sure your browser supports JSON parsing you can visit http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: the browser does support json...and im not getting the alert

Comment: @user1911914 If your not getting the alert, you need to start there. I'd recommend using Chromes inspector and opening the network tab to see if your getting a ny errors.

Comment: Its difficult to monitor using firebug since Im working on google maps api which takes a lot of data..

Comment: // php code 
and jquery code

![enter image description here][1]


![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pZRNt.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SwOZ4.jpg

These are the screenshots..

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` should do this way:

```
     var marker;
     $.ajax({
        url:'maps1.php',
        data:{},
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            marker = JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        complete:{
            alert(marker);
        }
   });
```

and `$.POST` should be like this:

```
   $.post('maps1.php',{},function(data){
       alert(data);
   },"json").done(function(data){
       markers=JSON.stringify(data);
       alert(markers);
   });
```

but i prefer to use `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

ajax string syntax below:

```
 var marker;
 $.ajax({
    url:'maps1.php',
    data:{},
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        marker = JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    complete:{
        alert(marker);
    }
});
```